# How to use pointers to return multiple values from a function in C

Tags: c

I am currently writing a program for a assigment which requires the use of a function to enable the user to input 3 vairables. I am having difficulty returning these variables to my main function, I have seen other similar questions previously asked and have attempted to use pointers but am unable to get it working. My attempt is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Function Header for positive values function
double get_positive_value(double* topSpeed, double* year, double* 
horsepower);

int main(void){

    int reRunProgram = 0; 

    while (reRunProgram==0)
    {
        //variable declarations
        double tS;
        double yR;
        double hP;
        int menuOption;
        int menuOption2;

        //menu
        printf("1.Create Bugatti\n");
        printf("2.Display Bugatti\n");      
        printf("3.Exit\n");

        //user choice
        scanf("%d", &menuOption);

        //Create car    
        if (menuOption == 1) {

            //run the get positive values function
            get_positive_value (&tS, &yR, &hP);

            printf("top speed is %lf\n", tS);
        }

        //Display car (but no car created)
        else if (menuOption == 2){
            printf("error no car created\n");
        }

        //Exit  
        else if (menuOption ==3){
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }   
    return 0;
}


double get_positive_value(double*  topSpeed, double* year, double* 
horsepower)
{
    do  {
        printf("Please enter the top speed of the bugatti in km/h\n");
        scanf("%lf", &topSpeed);
    } while(*topSpeed<=0);

    do{
        printf("Please enter the year of the bugatti, in four digit form (e.g. 1999)\n");
        scanf("%lf", &year);
    } while(*year<=0);

    do{
        printf("Please enter the horsepower of the bugatti\n");
        scanf("%lf", &horsepower);
    } while(*horsepower<=0);
}
```

Comment: C or C++? You tagged this question as C++, but you wrote "in C" in the title, which is it?

Comment: Apologies that was an error entering the tag, it is C (which I have edited to be correct)

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: Take the compiler's warning serious. Fix the code until no more warnings are issued. Do not do this by blindly casting away warnings.

Comment: What's the idea behind the semicolon here: `} else;`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't return multiple values from a function unless you wrap them in a `struct`. As far as pointers are concerned you can modify the values that you passed into the function from main. I think you're doing it wrong here :

```
scanf("%lf", &topSpeed);
```

Since `topSpeed` is a pointer to a double and you only need to pass the address of the variable you passed from main (not the address of pointer variable). You should instead do:

```
do {
    printf("Please enter the top speed of the bugatti in km/h\n");
    scanf("%lf", topSpeed);
} while(*topSpeed<=0);
do {
    printf("Please enter the year of the bugatti, in four digit form (e.g. 1999)\n");
    scanf("%lf", year);
} while(*year<=0);
do {
    printf("Please enter the horsepower of the bugatti\n");
    scanf("%lf", horsepower);
} while(*horsepower<=0);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You declared the variables `tS`, `yR` & `hP` inside the `main` function and passed them by reference to the `get_positive_value()` function.

So the **address** of the variables are being passed. Not the variables themselves.

In `get_positive_value()`, you are attempting to place some values into the 3 variables using `scanf()` where you should've given the address of the variables but gave the  *address of address* instead.
`&topSpeed` in `get_positive_value()` is like `&(&tS)` in `main()`.

Since you have passed them by reference, in `get_positive_value()`, you have the address of `tS`, `yR`, `hP` in `topSpeed`, `year`, `horsepower` respectively.

`topSpeed` itself is the address of `tS`. Not `&topSpeed`.

You should change
`scanf("%lf", &topSpeed);`
to
`scanf("%lf", topSpeed);`
(likewise for the other 2 variables)

Because `topSpeed` is having the address of the variable `tS` in `main()`. So if you say `&topSpeed` you are trying to access the 'address of address of `tS`'.

Answer (score 0):

When you do 
`*someptr` you are asking for the value, at the memory address this pointer is pointing at.

When you do a `scanf` and you use `&x` for a variable, you do it because you want to store  the value **at** that memory address. So when you do a `scanf` with a pointer, you don't use `*` because you pass a value instead of an address, to store the value at.

You don't use `&` either, because you pass the memory address of the pointer instead of the one you actually want to modify. This is your main error.
Lastly​, you could `return` those values all at once using a `struct`, but pointers are more elegant.

Hope I helped you and I was clear.