# find maximum and minimum value from array using recurrsion

Tags: c

I wrote a code to find the maximum and second maximum using recursion:

```
struct max_min
{
        int max;
        int min;
}obj;

int find_l_m(int a[], int size)
{
        int next_element;

        if (size == 1)
                return a[0];

        next_element = find_l_m(a, size-1);

        if (a[size-1] > next_element) {
                obj.max = a[size-1];
                obj.min = next_element;

                return a[size-1];
        } else {
                obj.max = next_element;
                obj.min = a[size-1];

                return next_element;
        }

}

int main()
{
        int a[] = {1, 11, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 10};

        find_l_m(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));
        printf("%d\n%d\n", obj.max, obj.min);
}
```

I have couple of query:

1. Can this be made more simple, should be able to return max and
   second max without using struct object.
2. How above code can be changed to find maximum (that it does) and minimum value from array

Comment: Using recursion for this particular purpose is a bad idea. Just iterating over the array once is going to be much more efficient in many ways. It is also poor design to use a global variable to store the results of a function. A better approach would be to write separate functions for highest and lowest, or returning multiple results in a pointer argument, or just sorting the array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The question is tagged C.

Comment: @Cheatah: Linear tail recursion captures iteration over an array quite well.

Comment: you're algorithm is wrong. For `{10, 11, 1}` it returns `{11,1}` what is not a valid pair for maximum and the second maximum. It looks that the code actually returns the minimum and the maximum of the array.

Comment: @Cheatah, scanning multiple times over the array may invalidate quite a lot of cache. It will likely degrage performance.  If possible it is still better to find both statistics in one run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recursion is good (assuming that it is good for anything) in finding max or min.

```
typedef struct 
{
        int max;
        int min;
}obj;

int max_min(int minmax, int arr[], size_t size)
{
    if(size == 1) return *arr;
    else 
    {
        int result = max_min(minmax, arr + 1, size - 1);
        if(minmax) return result <= *arr ? *arr : result;
        else return result >= *arr ? *arr : result;
    }
}

obj test(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    return (obj){max_min(1, arr, size), max_min(0, arr, size)};
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1,4,9,3,2,-4,0,2,3};
    obj o = test(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));

    printf("max = %d min = %d\n", o.max, o.min);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zGrYMYjx7

Comment: @0___________, wanted to know, are we storing, structure member in  {max_min(1, arr, size), max_min(0, arr, size)};} ?, and is it the first max_min(1, arr, size) return maximum value from array, right ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:

> Can this be made more simple, should be able to return max and second max without using struct object.

There are a couple of ways to return two (or more) values from one function in C. The first one, as you noted, is using a `struct`, this way:

```
// Define a struct holding two integers 
struct Pair_of_int {
    int a;
    int b;
 };


// Define a function returning a `PairOfInt`
struct Pair_of_int my_function(int[] a, int size) {
     struct Pair_of_int result;
     // Do some work
     result.a = /*...*/;
     result.b = /*...*/;
     return result;
 }
```

This is how you would call such a function in your main function :

```
struct Pair_of_int pair = my_function(...);
printf("First %d, second %d", pair.a, pair.b);
```

Note that this is not exactly what you have done in the code you've shown. In your code you have a **global** instance of your struct `max_min` that gets updated by the function. What you want is to use the structure as the **return value** of the function, as shown above.

The other way is to [use pointers to return multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435962/how-to-use-pointers-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c). Here if you want two `int`s you have to define your function to accept two pointers to `int` as arguments and use them to store the values.

```
void my_function(int[]a, int size, int* out_a, int* out_b) {
    // Do some work
    *out_a = /*...*/;
    *out_b = /*...*/;
}
```

Here as you can see the function returns nothing. Instead it uses the two pointers `out_a` and `out_b` to store the result. This is how you would use it in the main function :

```
int a; int b;
my_function(array, size, &a, &b);
printf("First %d, second %d", a, b);
```

You create two variables `a` and `b` that will hold the results and pass their **address** to `my_function` with the `&` operator.

> How above code can be changed to find maximum (that it does) and minimum value from array

This is shouldn't be too hard if you get the first case working correctly. You have to keep track of the two values separately. You might have to add some more arguments to your function for it to work recursively.

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be made more simple, should be able to return max and second max without using struct object.

You could factor out the update of a min-max structure with a single value into a separate function. Then, you could probably make your recursive function into a one-liner.

> How above code can be changed to find maximum (that it does) and minimum value from array

Well, you would need to:

- return a `struct max_min`.
- properly initialize your `struct max_min` (e.g. for the case of an empty array; defining the semantics appropriately).